# longtable body and head not the same width

Tags: longtable

I've got a problem : the width of the longtable body and head are not the same :

Here the code :

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c |} \hline
Num de logt : & \makecell{type de \\ financement}  &  \makecell{surface utile \\ ponderree} & taux de loyer & loyer & total charges\\ \hline
\endfirsthead

Num de logt : & \makecell{type de \\ financement}  &  \makecell{surface utile \\ ponderree} & taux de loyer & loyer & total charges\\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\\
\endlastfoot

1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

here an image of the result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h8xkPUXgC5fVSNgEAklf2C3pCLFIEK7d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Guilty of what? I have no problem. Did you compile twice? Also: don't use the ` center` environment with `longtable`s: they're automatically centred.

Comment: it works on the many page table but when it's a one page table the width bug

Comment: it works fine. you need to compile it twice. also your definition of `\endlastfoot` is wrong. correct is `\hline
\endlastfoot`, not `\\  \endlastfoot`.

Comment: you should get a message at the end of the document, telling you the widths have changed and to re-run latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your code after second compilation i obtain:

[image]

spurious last row is consequence of your definition of `lastfoot`:

```
\\
\endlastfoot
```

if you remove `\\` than you will obtain

[image]

remember: `longtable` had to be compiled twice!

complete code for your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell} 

\begin{document}    
\begin{longtable}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c |} \hline
Num de logt : & \makecell{type de \\ financement}  &  \makecell{surface utile \\ ponderree} & taux de loyer & loyer & total charges\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
Num de logt : & \makecell{type de \\ financement}  &  \makecell{surface utile \\ ponderree} & taux de loyer & loyer & total charges\\ \hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
\hline% i would omit it, it gives ugly result
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
1054& HLM/O  & 74.00 & 4.69  &  347.361 &  64.811 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```